# Does MS Exchange support redirecting

Tags: exchange, email-server

A, seemingly, simple question: Does MS Exchange support redirecting as per [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) section 3.6.6 (`Resent-*` headers)? Yet, the Internet (at least the parts I searched) doesn't turn up a conclusive answer.

I know redirecting is sometimes refered to as bouncing or remailing. I guess it depends on the perspective (client-side vs. server-side). What *I* mean is the redirect feature many mail clients offer: mutt, (al)pine, TB through an [extension](http://mailredirect.sourceforge.net/) and [Outlook](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_redirect.htm).

I was told by a postmaster that MS Exchange didn't support that. I get "5.7.1 Client does not have permission to send as this sender. Please check the message and try again." in my mail client when I attempt to redirect an email. From someone else, however, I learned that for him redirecting against an Exchange account worked just fine.

Comment: Is there an RFC or something you can refer to so that we're all on the same page as to what a redirect/bounce is?

Comment: Remailing(Redirect) and Bounce are very different things.  Given you expect Resent-* headers, this would not be a bounce.  A Bounce message should never add Resent-* headers.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I realize now that my question was ambiguous and, therefore, I updated it.